# Cannot resolve Promise in Node.js App with chrome-cookies-secure module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cookies, promise

I'm working on a local Node.js app that needs to access the Google Chrome cookies. I've found the [`chrome-cookies-secure`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-cookies-secure) library that seems to do the job but I just can't figure out what's wrong with the code below.

```
const chrome = require('chrome-cookies-secure');

const domains = [
    "google.com"
];

const resolveCookies = async () => {
    let result = [];
    for(domain of domains) {
        await chrome.getCookies(`https://${domain}/`,  (err, cookies) => { 
            result.push(cookies); 
            // console.log(cookies); //? This is going to correctly print the results
        })
    }
    return result;
}

const final = resolveCookies();
console.log(final); //! This is going to return a Promise { <pending> } object
```

The idea is that I just want to store the cookies from all the domains in a list but no matter what I cannot resolve the Promise.
I didn't see any examples with the async call for this module but if I don't use it it's going to return me an empty list after the script execution.

My Node Version: `v14.4.0`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `resolveCookies` returns a *promise* of the array - `async` functions **always** return a promise. Try `resolveCookies.then((final) => console.log(final))`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the suggestion, however I get back a `TypeError: resolveCookies.then is not a function`.

Comment: Sorry, typo; you need to *call* the function, `resolveCookies().then(...`

Comment: Sorry me also, I should have caught that :D
Anyway this bring me back to the empty list result `[]`

Comment: Does `chrome.getCookies` actually return a promise? If not, `await`ing it won't help at all.

Comment: So it looks like: `(property) getCookies: (uri: any, format: any, callback: any, profile: any) => Promise<any>`

Comment: Glancing at [the source code](https://github.com/bertrandom/chrome-cookies-secure/blob/master/index.js) I don't think that *does* properly synchronise. `getCookies` is `async`, but it doesn't await its call to `getDerivedKey`, which isn't `async` anyway. Try using [`Util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the implementation of `getCookies` is **not** correctly awaiting the asynchronous processes. You can see in [the implementation](https://github.com/bertrandom/chrome-cookies-secure/blob/master/index.js) that although `getCookies` itself is `async`, it calls `getDerivedKey` without awaiting it (and that function isn't `async` anyway).

Rather than trying to rely on this implementation, I'd suggest using [`Util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create a proper promise via the callback:

```
const util = require('util');

const chrome = require('chrome-cookies-secure');

const getCookies = util.promisify(chrome.getCookies);

// ...

const cookies = await getCookies(`https://${domain}/`);
```

Note that, as [Reece Daniels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10732370/reece-daniels) pointed out in the comments, the `getCookies` implementation actually takes a `profile` parameter *after* the callback; if you need to use that parameter, you can't use the built-in `promisify`. You'd have to wrap it yourself instead, this could look like e.g.:

```
const getCookies = (url, format, profile) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.getCookies(url, format, (err, cookies) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(cookies);
        }
    }, profile);
});
```

They [already tried to fix the promise upstream](https://github.com/bertrandom/chrome-cookies-secure/pull/21), but the PR hasn't been merged in nearly nine months.

---

Note that once you have a working function to call you can also convert:

```
const resolveCookies = async () => {
    let result = [];
    for(domain of domains) {
        await chrome.getCookies(`https://${domain}/`,  (err, cookies) => { 
            result.push(cookies); 
            // console.log(cookies); //? This is going to correctly print the results
        })
    }
    return result;
}
```

to simply:

```
const resolveCookies = () => Promise.all(domains.map((domain) => getCookies(`https://${domain}/`)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, as I understand it's something that belongs to the module's implementation itself. Didn't see the PR about this till now :)

Comment: @Void no problem, the library implementation (having an `async` function that doesn't actually resolve at the right time) is very confusing! But note https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Nice @jonrsharpe, 

I just read the `Util.promisify` you kindly linked, and I believe this will work in all cases, except where `profile` is passed, as `profile` becomes the last argument in the function call:

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original -> `Takes a function following the common error-first callback style, i.e. taking an (err, value) => ... callback as the last argument, and returns a version that returns promises.`

Just an observation, as I think this answer solves the OPs Q.. and it doesn't look likely my PR will get merged to that repo anytime soon.

Comment: @ReeceDaniels ah good point; I'll edit, thanks. And no, I wouldn't hold out much hope...

Answer (score -1):

An `async` function returns a `Promise`.
So your `resolveCookies` function will also return a `Promise` as you noticed.

You need to either chain the `console.log` with a `.then` e.g.

```
resolveCookies().then(console.log);
```

Or if you need to set it to a variable like `final` you need to await that `Promise` too. In that case you need an `async` IIFE:

```
(async () => {
    const final = await resolveCookies();
    console.log(final);
})();
```

Comment: Per the comments it's **not** that simple.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
const chrome = require('chrome-cookies-secure');

const domains = [
    "www.google.com"
];

const resolveCookies = async() => {
    let result = [];
    for (domain of domains) {
      const cookies = await getCookies(domain)
      result.push(cookies)
    }
    return Promise.resolve(result);
}

const getCookies = async (domain) => {
    chrome.getCookies(`https://${domain}/`,  (err, cookies) => { 
        return Promise.resolve(cookies);
    })
}

resolveCookies().then((resp) => {
    console.log('FINAL ',resp)
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('ERROR ', e)
})
```

Comment: Returning `Promise.resolve` from the callback **does not** make your `getCookies` implementation return a promise of the cookies. You also don't even attempt to handle the `err`.

Comment: Just making it `async` won't help, either. I've put an example of how to do that manually into my answer.